# Is there anyway to move (swap) an icon pinned to the taskbar by keyboard?

Tags: command-line, shortcut-keys, gnome-shell, shortcuts, taskbar

My Ubuntu version is default 18.04.

It seems to be configured via some macro or shell script, But I can't find and figure out.

Is there any way I can move (or swap) pinned Ubuntu taskbar icons using a simple key combination like <kbd>super</kbd> + whatever + arrow?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There is no built-in possibility to move the pinned icons through keystrokes. The pinned icons (and their order) are defined in a dconf setting, e.g.

```
org.gnome.shell favorite-apps ['firefox.desktop', 'org.gnome.Nautilus.desktop', 'zim.desktop', 'org.gnome.Terminal.desktop', 'libreoffice-writer.desktop', 'libreoffice-calc.desktop', 'libreoffice-impress.desktop', 'org.gnome.gedit.desktop']
```

Thus, at least, the pinned icons and/or their order could be changed in a script by changing the setting:

```
gsetting set org.gnome.shell favorite-apps ['...']
```

It would probably not be that easy to implement a keyboard interface that would allow to select an icon and move it with keystrokes. There is no way that I know to select the Ubuntu dash with the keyboard. In Standard Gnome Shell, however, without Ubuntu Dock active, one can reach the Dash in the overview with: <kbd>Super</kbd> <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>Alt</kbd>+<kbd>Tab</kbd>.

Comment: @Zanna I was assuming the default Ubuntu 18.04 environment. Rather than closing the question immediately, the OP should probably be given the change to indicate the details.

Comment: OP edited the question, it is indeed default 18.04.  Nonetheless, I would not jump to assumption in general before OP actually edits the post. Besides questions always can be reopened